# Using pytrends to scrape coronavirus data

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
kw = ['Coronavirus']

import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en us',tz=360)

kw = ['Coronavirus']
search_df = pytrends.get_historical_interest(kw)
search_df
```

The above is my code. I'm not sure how to interepret my output? Also I was hoping the output would be more rich in terms of data such as indicating where that keyword was trending.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is all wrong. Try:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360, retries=10, backoff_factor=0.5)

search_df = pytrend.get_historical_interest(
    keywords=['Coronavirus'],
    year_start=2020,
    year_end=2020,
    month_end=4,
    month_start=2

)
print(search_df)

pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['Coronavirus'])

# Interest Over Time
interest_over_time_df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
print(interest_over_time_df.tail())

# Interest by Region
interest_by_region_df = pytrend.interest_by_region()
print(interest_by_region_df.head())
```

Mainly from https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/examples/example.py